# How can I define an S3 method for an unevaluated assignment expression?

Tags: r, r-s3, non-standard-evaluation

> **tl;dr**: `R CMD check` complains when I implement a generic for the S3 class `<-`, because it thinks that the function is a replacement function with incorrect arguments.

I need to define a set of S3 generics to walk an AST of unevaluated R expressions.

For demonstration purposes, consider the following S3 generic and its methods:

```
walk = function (x) UseMethod('walk')

walk.default = function (x) message('default')

walk.name = function (x) message('name')

walk.call = function (x) message('call')
```

This works fine:

```
tests = alist('2', c, f(1))

invisible(lapply(tests, walk))
```

```
default
name
call
```

However, there are quite a few call expressions whose S3 class isn’t `call`; for example:

```
tests2 = alist(for (x in y) ., if (.) ., x <- .)
invisible(lapply(tests2, walk))
```

```
default
default
default
```

… oops. What I *want* for these expressions to be treated as calls. I can do this by adding more methods:

```
walk.for = function (x) message('for')

walk.if = function (x) message('if')

`walk.<-` = function (x) message('<-')

# … and so on for other syntax constructs.
```

And now I’m getting the expected result when calling `walk`:

```
for
if
<-
```

However, this code is part of a package, and `R CMD check` complains about the definition of `walk.<-` because it thinks that the function is a replacement function:

> ```
> W  checking replacement functions ...
>     ‘walk.<-’
>   The argument of a replacement function which corresponds to the right
>   hand side must be named ‘value’.
> ```

And I understand *why* I’m getting the warning (indeed, this looks like a botched attempt at defining a replacement function for `walk.`). But of course this *isn’t* a replacement function, so the warning is a false positive. So how am I supposed to implement an S3 generic for the class `<-` unambiguously? Or is this a bug in `R CMD check`? Can I get rid of the warning? I can’t add additional arguments to the functions.

Comment: It's not ideal, but why not just handle the special case of `<-` inside the `default` method? i.e. `walk.default = function (x) if(class(x) == '<-') message('<-') else message('default')`

Comment: Or does using `setMethod('walk', '<-', function (x) message('<-'))` perhaps pass without complaint from R CMD check? It seems to dispatch properly.

Comment: @AllanCameron Ah, hm. Interesting hack. Actually `setMethod` is for S4, and using it with S3 breaks inheritance (unless `setOldClass` is used) but `registerS3method` instead works as well, and `R CMD check .` is OK with it. — Write an answer! (The workaround in the first comment obviously works but is precisely what I wanted to avoid.)

Comment: Sounds like you answered it yourself really Konrad - `registerS3method` is obviously better than `setMethod`. I'm mildly surprised that the CMD check doesn't complain about it though.

Comment: @AllanCameron Why would it complain? Because the function is documented as “internal”? Actually the “official” solution is probably to use `.S3method` which, despite being hidden, isn’t internal (however, it does exactly the same thing except for irrelevant details, and its documentation is effectively nonexistent, except [in a blog post](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2019/08/19/s3-method-lookup/)).

Comment: Just lack of knowledge on my part really - the docs for the ns-internals imply that mortals may not use these functions without facing the wrath of the R gods. I know that R CMD prevents use of some ns functions like `:::`, and assumed it also polices (some of) the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Writing R Extensions*, section *1.5.2 Registering S3 methods*](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Registering-S3-methods) provides a workaround solution:

> It is possible to specify a third argument to `S3method`, the function to be used as the method, for example
>
> ```
> S3method(print, check_so_symbols, .print.via.format)
> ```
>
> when `print.check_so_symbols` is not needed.

This means that, instead of defining `` `walk.<-` ``, we do the following:

##### Implementation in `R/‹some-file›.r`:

```
walk_assign = function (x) message('<-')
```

(Unlike for other S3 methods, the function name is unimportant.)

##### `NAMESPACE` declaration:

```
S3method(walk, '<-', walk_assign)
```

This effectively does the same as calling `.S3method('walk', '<-', \(x) message('<-'))` inside a regular R script. Interestingly, `.S3method()` *also* seems to work inside a package (instead of the above `NAMESPACE`-based solution), but the function’s documentation says not to use it in packages so this might break in the future.

---

Of course an arguably simpler solution, as commented by Allan Cameron, is to fuse the `<-` case with `default` and using `if` inside `walk.default` to disambiguate:

```
walk.default = function (x) {
    if (inherits(x, '<-')) {
        message('<-')
    } else {
        message('default')
    }

}
```

However, personally I prefer not to mix S3 dispatch with `if`.

Comment: Very nice answer. Are you allowed to do `S3method(walk, '<-', walk.call)` etc to minimise the number of function definitions?

Comment: @AllanCameron Oh absolutely, if all you need is a method for all calls, by all means merge those definitions.